# Select boostrap lost styles after click

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, select

Hi everybody i have another problem with bootstrap. When I push the button for register the information all select control lost the styles. Maybe i did something wrong. Please help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $(function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: does `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();` apply the style to your elements? if you don't write the code above, your controls doesn't get the style?

Comment: when the page load all my controls have the style but when i push the button all controls lost the style

Comment: then why did you have this  `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();`? what is it for?

Comment: that is for select control <select id="dplHorario" runat="server" class="selectpicker"</select>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RegisterStartupScript` for to insert Javascript code in your page.

When you push the button in your page write this code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Funct", "$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();", true);
```

and now your controls should be styled.

Also I recommend put this line in a function, because maybe you are going to use it in more events.